# Why a user with 1 reputation can post a comment?

Tags: soporte, comentarios, reputación

I saw in this question: [¿"Binding" en castellano?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15534/8966) that the user [pablowako](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/11492/pablowako?tab=topactivity) post a comment in the question, but the user have 1 reputation.

[image]

It is normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know what happens. The comment was posted as a answer and one of the has admins migrated the answer as a comment.

Comment: I can confirm that this is indeed the case. Anyone with 10,000+ reputation (or a mod) can see the answer, which was converted to a comment by Joze.